# How can you find papers that have the largest bibliography (i.e., the highest number of references)?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

Does anybody keep track of such things? How would one go about finding out about something like that?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Do you mean the absolute largest, or are you thinking more along the lines of the number of references per page (or word)?

Comment: It sounds like something you would have to write a custom program. But then it'll be challenging cause there are billions of papers out there and more of them are closed.

Comment: Usually surveys, by definition. But how to find it specifically... I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

"The article with the most references at 3,112 is [World checklist of hornworts and liverworts](https://doi.org/10.3897/phytokeys.59.6261) in the journal PhytoKeys", containing 12,274 in-text citations.

Source: Daniel Himmelstein, "On author versus numeric citation styles" (12 March 2018), *Satoshi Village* (personal blog), at https://blog.dhimmel.com/citation-styles/

The reference list is 160 pages long.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some programming skills, there may be some APIs for Google Scholar that would allow you to search for papers with large bibliographies.  See e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938110/does-google-scholar-have-an-api-available-that-we-can-use-in-our-research-applic

I suspect the papers with the largest bibliographies are likely to be reviews, which are likely to cite very well established papers, so start by finding papers with lots of citations (which should be easier to find) and then search the papers that cite them.

(but +1 to @anpami ;o)